# Как в Python упрощать математические выражения с неизвестными переменными?

Tags: python

Пример:

1,75 * x / 1,2 - math.sqrt(x) + (1 - 0,43 * x)

Как упрощать выражения такого типа в Python?

Comment: Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос, нужно видеть код на питоне

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что я не знаю как в коде реализовать решение подобных математических выражений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль [`sympy`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) (`pip install sympy`).

При создании выражения он автоматически частично его упрощает:

```
from sympy import sqrt, Rational
from sympy.abc import x

f = 1.75 * x / 1.2 - sqrt(x) + (1 - 0.43 * x)
print(f)
```

Вывод: `-sqrt(x) + 1.02833333333333*x + 1`

Чтобы избавиться от периодической десятичной дроби, можно преобразовать все значения с плавающей точкой в объекты [`Rational`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-rational-method/) (рациональные дроби, т.е. например `Rational("1.75")` превратится в дробь `7/4`):

```
f = Rational("1.75") * x / Rational("1.2") - sqrt(x) + (1 - Rational("0.43") * x)
print(f)
```

Вывод: `-sqrt(x) + 617*x/600 + 1`

Для упрощения более сложных выражений можно использовать функцию [`symplify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html). Пример из документации:

```
from sympy import simplify, cos, sin
from sympy.abc import x, y

a = (x + x**2)/(x*sin(y)**2 + x*cos(y)**2)
print(a)  # (x**2 + x)/(x*sin(y)**2 + x*cos(y)**2)
print(simplify(a))  # x + 1
```